# Observing Realm's properties object with ReactiveCocoa, how to handle when an object becomes invalidated

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, realm, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to implement a ViewModel.

I want to bind the ViewModel to a Model (RealmObject).

I am using Reactive Cocoa (2.5) to bind the ViewModel to the Model.

Something like:

```
RAC(self, name)        = RACObserve(self, boundedProfile.name);
RAC(self, pictureUrl)  = RACObserve(self, boundedProfile.pictureUrl);
RAC(self, birthday)    = RACObserve(self, boundedProfile.birthdate);
```

My question is what happens if at a later point I delete the profile and it becomes invalidated? Should I remove all the observers? Ho do I do that with ReactiveCocoa?

I am using the Objective-C versions of ReactiveCocoa and Realm.

Answer (score 1):

I think `RLMObject.invalidated` property conforms to KVO. So you can probably just do the following if you want to break subscription once the profile is invalidated:

```m
RACSignal *invalidationSignal = [[RACObserve(self, boundedProfile.invalidated)
    filter:^BOOL(BOOL invalid) {
        return invalid == true; // We're only interested in the cases where it was invalidated.
    }]
    replayLast]; // For multicasting the same value for all subscribers.

RAC(self, name)        = [RACObserve(self, boundedProfile.name) 
    takeUntil:invalidationSignal]; // Once a value passes here, the subscription breaks.

RAC(self, pictureUrl)  = [RACObserve(self, boundedProfile.pictureUrl) 
    takeUntil:invalidationSignal];

RAC(self, birthday)    = [RACObserve(self, boundedProfile.birthdate) 
    takeUntil:invalidationSignal];
```

### Note:

I would suggest not using your database models in the ViewModel directly and have them mapped to additional models only for presentation, that way it would be easier to handle such cases.

Comment: Nice answer. The part I was missing was that the filter for checking the invalid bool is necessary.